# With 500k in Netherlands, Best path towards regular income, settle mortgage and rent or sell and invest?

Tags: investing, mortgage, banking, rental-property, investment-income

Currently I live in Netherlands. I have come to a crossroad and I'm interested to hear other opinions and advice on investment for a regular stable long term income. My ultimate intention is to secure a regular 2-3k monthly income, so I can move to my family abroad and help out there. I understand there are so many variables in this scenario, and I've turned it over and looked at options. This is what I've come up with.

I currently have a house worth 500k+, with mortgage less than 200k remaining. The house has more than doubled since I originally purchased. House is in Netherlands.

Also I'm at the point where I have enough liquid cash from investments to settle the 200k mortgage in its entirety and an extra buffer for 5+ months.

I'm wondering at this point if I should use the cash to pay off the mortgage, and prepare to rent out the house, with the intention of having it fully managed. I believe the house will fetch 2.5-3k monthly before any management, taxes or deductions. What I think is that I will still have the paid-off house itself, that can later be sold in a decade or so, while I collect rent until then.

Or if I should sell the house and contents, consolidate all the cash into a 500k pot and invest that into an S&P 500 tracker, and sip off that? In this scenario, I would not have the house to deal with, but I still want to guarantee an income without depleting the pot too much.

Otherwise if there is some other vehicle or path I should consider (That I can have control over, and will have access for income)? I've looked at other options like Investment Funds,  Savings Deposits and crypto trackers (crypto could go anywhere but is something I understand).

Edit: I have a reasonable amount of experience with trading stocks and crypto, that is to say I'm not afraid of investments, but I'm looking for a relatively hands-off "stable" long term investment (Mentioned S&P tracker, ETF or such) rather than day trading. The reason is I intend to focus on some family obligations in a less expensive country for a few years or decades, while my rental/investments provide a reasonable return to support my life while I focus on that.
I'm also familiar with running my own business being a successful freelance contractor for many years, so I would say I'm fairly savvy in managing business and such. Just some context.

Edit2: Lastly, I'm after having some discussions with some direct neighbours who just sold a month ago, I'm definitely now leaning toward selling and investing the money. Renting sounds great, if I could ensure good, stable, long term tenants, but I have heard many times by now that is a big ask. With the housing market being what it is right now, its also a good time to sell.

Edit3: Probably should clarify, I'm not American, although I've been assumed to be many times in my life. Also, I'm looking to find an appropriate investment vehicle that I can manage from Netherlands, as that's where I plan to keep my funds, main accounts and registered business. I have heard and seen online many options for Americans, but I'm struggling to find many options that are relative to Dutch residents. I'm not super knowledgable with all the types of investment available though, that could give me a 5-7% return. Any advice would be appreciated?

Comment: Are you an American only temporarily living in the Netherlands or will you retire there?

Comment: @Nosjack I'm not American, but yes I've been resident (Not citizen) in Netherlands for over a decade and paid taxes from day 1, so I will get some pension eventually at retirement. I don't intend to retire in Netherlands in the long run, honestly.

Comment: You mentioned the S&P which is why I asked. Will you at least retire in the EU?

Comment: Managing a house rental from overseas is a recipe for disaster, or at least very expensive management fees. Crypto is not an investment, it is fool's gold that could blow up in your face. 500k earning 5% interest in a bond or similar would earn you 25k a year, more than the 2k / month you are after, at minimal risk.

Comment: Nosjack I have considered retiring in the EU, but there's really nothing for me here family-wise, so just the good friends I've made since moving here and whatever possessions I have, like the house and contents.

@Grade'Eh'Bacon I'm afraid you're right, I've been thinking more about this. I spoke to my direct neighbours yesterday, who just signed the contract to sell a month ago, and they did very well. I'm definitely leaning now towards selling rather than renting.

The real remaining question is how do I secure a stable 7% on 500k in Europe/EU, that I can draw from?

Comment: This is too general for a Stack Exchange question. There are many ways you could move forward, all involving trading off risk versus reward. Remember that not keeping up with inflation is also a risk that must be traded off. This really isn't a different question from the reams of existing advice here in how to pick an investment strategy, plus the repeated advice that paying for a once-a-decade professional review by a fiduciary investment counselor is the best way to get advice tuned to your specific needs and comfort level and time horizon... so this is largely a duplicate too

Comment: (My "best path" 20 years ago was a significantly different balance than my "best path" today, and mine may be significantly different from yours.)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I appreciate your concern that this might be too general, which is why I tried to mention the things I've researched and experienced already. If you have questions, please ask. I don't think I'm the smartest, so I look to others who know more and been through it for opinions. I have a certified mortgage advisor and accountant that I consult as well so I'm not doing too stupid. Still, in the end I want to ask here and see if there are ideas that I might be missing. That's good advice to get a once-a-decade review, and I am looking now and what I need to do very soon.

Comment: For what it's worth, your 7% goal is roughly the historical market-rate-of-return for the US stock market (usually quoted as closer to 8%), so you shouldn't have much trouble earning that, modulo the usual stock market randomness. I'm about 10% average return over the past 25 years, 7.8% over the past 5 (weird boom/bust/recovery during the plague years), with nothing more than a set of index funds.

Comment: @keshlam oh so you're actually doing this, that's fantastic for you. You're doing it with a set of Index Funds, which is managed ETFs or you're doing that yourself? The 5-7% target I have in mind is indeed based upon stable recommendations on market return. Currently I'm considering direct investing using ETFs, but in your experience is it better to hand it all over to a managed fund? Have you seen that there are any limits on accessing your funds if you have an emergency or unforseen circumstance? My hope is to be conservative and grow my pot as well as skim a 5-7% return.

Comment: @keshlam I've been doing a lot of numbers on what is possible, also have used ficalc with a 100% stock over 25 years, for 500k. A 24k annual return shows a 92.2% probability of success, and 30k return shows 73.4% when adjusted for inflation. When not adjusted though, a 30k return shows 96.9% and strong chances of the fund doubling in value. I know these are just simulations, and its impossible to say what might happen. I'd definitely need to seek help and advice from professionals every 5-10 years. I'm just curious to know what you think of these numbers?

Comment: Doubling your money in 10 years requires average of about 7.2% return each year. Quite achievable. Of course that's ignoring inflation's effect on the value of that money. To double the value in 10 years you need 7.2% over inflation, which is a lot harder. But with a 25 year target, it shouldn't be hard to double the value; I haven't yet run the numbers on that one. Compounding is a wonderful thing.

Comment: All you need to double value in 25 years is a bit more than 2.8% above inflation. So unless averaged yearly inflation is 5% or higher, market rate of return will still do it. With lower inflation rates, you do better.

Comment: Kareem, you should edit your specific goals into the original question; comments are considered ephemeral and may go away. Once you're done that, I'll be able to turn my calculations into an Answer.

Comment: Managed funds have a _very_ hard time producing enough income to offset their high fees. Websearch "Buffett Bet". A mix of low-fee index funds does pretty respectably. (ETF vs traditional mutual fund makes little difference that I can see, except perhaps for some tax structuring.)

Comment: The big advantage with index funds is that you don't have to do anything when their dishwasher breaks. Unlike tenants.

Comment: If you simply looking for a specific amount of income per month, have you looked into annuities?

Answer (score 2):

500K in laddered US 4-week TBills (5.375%) would kick off 513 a week in interest. No risk, if you trust the US government. ;-)

Comment: I looked into this, but this looks like its for US citizens/residents only. I'd be looking for an investment vehicle I can utilise within Europe/EU. I've looked into a few things I've mentioned already, and stocks ETF trackers seems to be an idea I'd think about seriously. What would you think?

Comment: @kareem You seem to be all over the map with how you might invest. Crypto -> Real estate -> Interest-earning bond -> diversified ETF; these are all completely different from eachother. Quick example - a t-bill earning 5% gives you 2k / month, but it won't grow over time; a diversified stock ETF will most likely grow in the long-term, but will fluctuate over the course of months/years, and won't safely give you monthly income. Please don't just take someone's say-so on how to proceed, $500k is way to much to be cavalier about. You have a lot more to figure out before pulling the trigger.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I appreciate you don't know me, but I'm typically a long-term and cautious decision maker, and this is why I've done well my life. I know not to "do what random internet people say" so maybe chill a bit? My point of this post is I'm laying out things I've got experience with, options I know, and things on my mind I've been thinking about for a long time. I'm asking for opinions, and options I may not have considered (That I can actually use unlike US Bonds or something). I have had a lot of success with real estate, crypto and stocks, I know what I'm talking about. Any ideas?

Comment: @Kareem I'm advising caution, and focus on how you move forward. Take offense if you'd like, I guess.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Oh jeez, I'm asking you if you have any ideas that I can actually use and I'm very cautious already. I'm literally focusing on how to move forward, and showing everything I've looked at and researched, and you say I'm "all over the map". Your responses have a air of negativity/pessimism to them, but I have tried to ignore that, and now you accuse me of being offended? Ok man, I don't have time for being offended by internet talk if that makes you feel better then keep projecting.